# Search Google Play Apps in PHP?

Tags: php, android, web-services, api, google-play

I want to search Google Play for Android Apps inside one of my web apps that is built in PHP. Is there any way to do so? Any webservice or API or something like that? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661434/does-google-play-have-an-api

Comment: I need the same for Google Play which is for Android

Comment: Amit Do you need a result set for the search query or is it OK to open the web page of Google Play directly?

Comment: @Mukund yea, I want result set. Is there any way available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unofficial API to work with here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

But Google has not provided an official Google Play API as of yet.